# Preserve original token in ICUTokenizerFactory

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, tokenize

I am using `solr.ICUTokenizerFactory` to index my `firstName` and `lastName` field, So that i can tokenize thing based on language specific word boundries.

```
<fieldType name="text_icu" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

However I have a use case which i am trying to figure out. lets say I have something like `"steve-jobs"` in firstName.
this is being tokenized into two tokens.

> steve, jobs

However if i do a wild card search for

> steve-jo*

it wont find anything becuase there is no token like that.

My problem will be solved if I can preserve the orignal token also.
so while indexing  somehow i can generate three token like this

> steve,jobs,steve-jobs

Is there a way i can preserve the original token ?

I am using **DSE 4.8.12**.

Or is there any other way i can solve this. Any pointers appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the WordDelimiterFilterFactory in conjunction with the ICUTokenizerFactory. WordDelimiterFilterFactory has a preserveOriginal option:

```
<fieldType name="text_icu" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
         preserveOriginal="1"
     />
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

Comment: That did not work. I think before it even go to the WordDelimiterFilterFactory. the ICUTokenizerFactory already has split the tokens into two. and the WordDelimiterFilterFactory will operate on those tokens which are provided by the ICUTokenizerFactory and the orignal is lost before it comes to WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Comment: Yeah, I think you would have to add a rulefile to make ICU work more like the WhitespeaceTokenizerFactory:  `<tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory" 
rulefiles="Latn:Latin-break-only-on-whitespace.rbbi"/>` This rulefile can be found in the solr source - in solr 5.0.0 it's in the lucene/analysis/icu/src/test/org/apache/lucene/analysis/icu/segmentation directrory

Comment: I am using Datastax(dse 4.8.12) . do you know how to add the rulefile in dse?